# Rails Install fcgi on my mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastcgi

I'm using Rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.2.  I've added gem 'fcgi' (fastcgi) to my Gemfile, but when I run bundle install it fails on the fcgi.

output:

```
Installing fcgi (0.9.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for fcgiapp.h... no
checking for fastcgi/fcgiapp.h... no

make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fcgi- 0.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fcgi-0.9.1/ext/fcgi/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing fcgi (0.9.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install fcgi -v '0.9.1'` succeeds before bundling.
Installing fcgi (0.9.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/johndcowan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for fcgiapp.h... no
checking for fastcgi/fcgiapp.h... no

make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fcgi-0.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fcgi-0.9.1/ext/fcgi/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing fcgi (0.9.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install fcgi -v '0.9.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then, I ran the gem install as suggested:

```
johns-MacBook-Pro:drywall johndcowan$ sudo gem install fcgi -v '0.9.1'
Fetching: fcgi-0.9.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fcgi:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/johndcowan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for fcgiapp.h... no
checking for fastcgi/fcgiapp.h... no

make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fcgi-0.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fcgi-0.9.1/ext/fcgi/gem_make.out
johns-MacBook-Pro:drywall johndcowan$
```

I found a user with the same problem and he/she installed fcgi_devel using yum which solved his/her problem with fcgi.  I tried instaling using port but it won't work.  The same site said I do not need yum.

```
sudo port install fcgi-devel
Error: Port fcgi-devel not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If using Homebrew, try `brew install fastcgi` first.